# How to Check if an user account exists or not (on local machine) in windows?

Tags: windows, javascript, user-accounts

I am trying to verify whether a particular user exists on the local computer. The one solution that I can do is parsing the output of command Net user . But is there any better solution than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can possibly use WMI with a query such as "select * from Win32_UserAccount where LocalAccount = True" or similar. If you are just looking for a specific account you can be able to restrict the WMI query more. See [Win32_UserAccount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394507%28VS.85%29.aspx). You may also just be able to use [GetObject](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb684728.aspx) (which may be more efficient), but I don't know how to formulate that.

You can follow the template/code at http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/6967 (which is not relating to user accounts :-) to setup/create the WMI ActiveX object, execute the query, and enumerate the results.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks pst. I tried it and is working. The code can be like var wmiobj = GetObject(winmgmts:\\\\.\\root\\cimv2");
var query =  "SELECT * FROM Win32_UserAccount Where LocalAccount = True And Name = '<name>'";
    
    var users = wmiobj.ExecQuery(query);
    if users.count is zero user doesn't exist. else user exists